# TypeError: setState is not a function in at a button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a state [profile, setProfile] in my general context provider that renders a profile component when the profile button is clicked in the nav section of the app.this profile component, however has a child component to update the profile that's being rendered whenever a button (update profile) is clicked. The way I did is that I passed the setProfile state down from the generalContext and set it to false inside the function that the update button uses. But I get this error `TypeError: setShowProfile is not a function at onUpdateProfileClick` whenever the button is clicked.

I tried doing it as stated above and i expected it to work but it didn't:

```
const [showUpdateProfile, setShowUpdateProfile] = useState(false);
const onUpdateProfileClick = () => {
    setUpdateProfile(true);
    setProfile(false);
};
```

Edit from comment:

```
const { setProfile } = useGeneralContext();
const [showUpdateProfile, setShowUpdateProfile] = useState(false);
const onUpdateProfileClick = () => {
  setShowUpdateProfile(true);
  setProfile(false);
};
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question. It is self explainable

Comment: You have typed 4 different variations of the function name throughout the question. Is it `setProfile` or `setShowProfile` or `setShowUpdateProfile` or `setUpdateProfile`

Comment: As pilchard said, you mentionned `setShowProfile` as en error but it's not in your code.

Comment: setProfile is a state updater that can be set to true or false and comes from the generalContext to render the profile component. the setShowProfile was a mistake, there's nothing like that in my code. I think it's what I used before changing it to setProfile. the updateProfile and setUpdateProfile is a state whose updater is set to true or false to render the update profile dynamically. setShowUpdateProfile is a typo. Do you understand now?

Comment: the error is setProfile

Comment: Can you show your context provider and how you export `setProfile` ?
How do you import `useGeneralContext` ?
And are you sure to have your component inside your provider ?